# How can i test this decorator?

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

Thats basically the model of the code. I tried somethings but i`m new at testing, so the lines isnt been covered.

So, I don't have idea of how I can acess and testing the content from createParamDecorator(). Or of how I test the headers, dto, and everything.
I tried to mock de ExecutionContext value and the switchToHttp() and put everything to return null and the test pass. But the lines wasn't covered.

```
import { plainToClass } from 'class-transformer';
// The import below fails
import { ClassType } from 'class-transformer/ClassTransformer';
import { validateOrReject } from 'class-validator';

export const RequestHeader = createParamDecorator(
  async (value:  any, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {

    // extract headers
    const headers = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest().headers;

    // Convert headers to DTO object
    const dto = plainToClass(value, headers, { excludeExtraneousValues: true });
    
    // Validate 
    await validateOrReject(dto);

    // return header dto object 
    return dto;
  },
);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Where does `createParamDecorator` come from?

Comment: It come from @nestjs>comon>http>create-route-param-metadata